# merge by id but replace old data with new data in some columns

Tags: r, data-wrangling

Basically, I have a dataframe that has some data that need to be replaced with data in a different dataframe. Some of the observations need to be changed in only a few of many columns.

To illustrate, say I have a dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(index = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), 
                  var1 = c(40, 22, 12, 4, 0),
                  var2 = c(75, 55, 65, 15, 0),
                  var3 = c(9, 18, 81, 3, 0),
                  var4 = c(1, 11, 21, 61, 0),
                  var5 = c(-1, -2, -3, -4, 0),
                  var6 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0))

    index   var1   var2   var3   var4   var5   var6
1     a     40     75      9      1     -1      0
2     b     22     55     18     11     -2      1
3     c     12     65     81     21     -3      0
4     d      4     15      3     61     -4      1
5.    e      0      0      0     0       0      0
```

Then, some better data for observations of "b" and "c" come along, but only for variables "var2" and "var3":

```
df2 <- data.frame(index = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 
                  var1 = c(40, 22, 12, 4),
                  var2 = c(75, 550, 650, 15),
                  var3 = c(9, 180, 810, 3),
                  var4 = c(1, 11, 21, 61))

  index var1 var2 var3 var4
1     a   40   75    9    1
2     b   22  550  180   11
3     c   12  650  810   21
4     d    4   15    3   61
```

I want the resulting data frame:

```
   index var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6
1     a   40   75    9    1   -1    0
2     b   22  550  180   11   -2    1
3     c   12  650  810   21   -3    0
4     d    4   15    3   61   -4    1
5     e    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Any tips (particularly any tidyverse solutions to offfer?) I have played around with `mutate`, `across`, and `replace` but can't seem to get it.

**Clarification**: I'd like the new values for var2 and var3 to be replaced with those from df2 wherever the index values are found in df1. Everything else should stay the same. The dataset I am working on has the index values show up many times. I tried the following, but something is wrong with the syntax:

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(across(c(var2, var3),
           ~if_else(index %in% df2$index),
                     .[df2$index],
                     .))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update II: after new clarification: removed the previous answer:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  arrange(index) %>% 
  mutate(across(var1:var4, ~ifelse(index=="b" |
                                     index == "c", lead(.), .))) %>% 
  na.omit()
```

```
  index var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6
1     a   40   75    9    1   -1    0
3     b   22  550  180   11   -2    1
5     c   12  650  810   21   -3    0
7     d    4   15    3   61   -4    1
9     e    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The dataset I am working with has dozens of columns in the "df1" that are not in "df2", so this method would be a little clunky.

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for my dataset either as the number of rows differs in df1 and df2 (with many more in df1). I edited the post to make it clearer that in the desired dataframe there are more observations than in df2. my apologies.

Comment: Please see my new edit!

Comment: Thanks, this works for my example. If there are multiple rows with the same index value (e.g., "b" and "c" show up in many different rows) could you easily modify this code so that anytime "b" or "c" showed up it would replace the values in var2 and var3 with those from df2?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data you gave in the OP, and the fact that the 'better' observations are larger numbers, the following seems to give the desired result:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(index = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), 
                  var1 = c(40, 22, 12, 4, 0),
                  var2 = c(75, 55, 65, 15, 0),
                  var3 = c(9, 18, 81, 3, 0),
                  var4 = c(1, 11, 21, 61, 0),
                  var5 = c(-1, -2, -3, -4, 0),
                  var6 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0))


df2 <- data.frame(index = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 
                  var1 = c(40, 22, 12, 4),
                  var2 = c(75, 550, 650, 15),
                  var3 = c(9, 180, 810, 3),
                  var4 = c(1, 11, 21, 61))


get_best <- function(col){
  value <- max(unlist(col), na.rm=TRUE)
  return(value)
}

a <- bind_rows(df1,df2) %>% 
  group_by(index) %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols=everything(),
                .fns=get_best)) %>% 
  unique()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 7
# Groups:   index [5]
  index  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        40    75     9     1    -1     0
2 b        22   550   180    11    -2     1
3 c        12   650   810    21    -3     0
4 d         4    15     3    61    -4     1
5 e         0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks, but I made the "better" values larger numbers just for ease of viewing the desired changes,  so this method wouldn't really work.